# jQuery realtime validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

i am trying to validate some fields in my webpage s an input can only take a number. But it is not working.
this is the html:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label class="control-label" for="mcc">GSM.Identity.MCC</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mcc" id="mcc" value="${mcc}">
                <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
```

and this is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mcc").on('keypress',function(){
            if(!$.isNumeric(this.val())){
                $(this).parent("div").removeClass("has-feedback").addClass("has-error");
            }
            else{
                $(this).parent("div").removeClass("has-feedback").addClass("has-success");
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

i have tried altering and changing in someways, it gives no result whatsoever.
note: i am using bootstrap for css and styles, "hass-error" class marks the input red

Comment: You can improve one more thing - try to validate after keyup, not after keypress. See here why: http://jsfiddle.net/vbxtbgaL/  When you delete value and type number, keypress is validating form from second character.

Comment: i usually provide all three (keypress, keydown, keyup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
if(!$.isNumeric(this.val())){
```

to this:

```
if(!$.isNumeric(this.value)){
```

or more jQuery way:

```
if(!$.isNumeric($(this).val())){
```

and in the `else` part, may be in some case you need to remove the `has-error` class too:

```
else{
    $(this).parent("div")
           .removeClass("has-feedback has-error")
           .addClass("has-success");
}
```

Comment: no matter what i try, i am even logging messages into the console, i am getting no result not even in the console. i guess the problem is how i am loading the script. maybe (document).ready should not be the case here

Answer (score 0):

HTML5

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control" name="mcc" id="mcc" value="${mcc}">
```

Notice the input type is now number instead of text.

Comment: i know this is an alternative, but it wont work with browsers that doesn't support html5